# How to use the pattern matcher correctly with android studio?

Tags: android, regex, url, pattern-matching, bufferedreader

I have been working on creating an app. It came to my attention that I need to use the **pattern matcher** to take information from a website and display it on the Android app. I am still a little new to Android App Development but I think I am decent at Java. I tried this exact same code in Eclipse and it worked so I am a little bit baffled why Android Studio would be any different.

Essentially, I have a textview that I am trying to populate with States from wikipedia. These states are the states that have beaches in them. The regex that I wrote on Eclipse grabs all states and even some extra US territories and displays them in the console, but this is not the case in Android.

```
public static String patternMatcher()
{
    try {
        URL getUrlContent = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_beaches_in_the_United_States");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getUrlContent.openStream()));
        String line;

        Pattern stateForBeach = Pattern.compile("<h3>(.*>)(.*?)</span><span class=\"mw-editsection\"><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">", Pattern.DOTALL);
        //Pattern beach = Pattern.compile("<li><a href=\"(.*?>)(.*?)</a></li>");
        Matcher matcher1;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            matcher1 = stateForBeach.matcher(line);
            if (matcher1.find()) {
                matcherString = "States: " + matcher1.group(2);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }
    return matcherString;
}
```

This is the method to add the states to the textview

```
public void addItemsToTextView()
{
    patternMatcherTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.patternMatcherTextView);
    System.out.println(patternMatcher());
    patternMatcherTextView.setText(patternMatcher());
}
```

And this is the onCreate app method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_which_beach);
    stateSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stateSpinner);
    patternMatcherTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.patternMatcherTextView);
    patternMatcherTextView.setText(patternMatcher());
    addItemsToStateSpinner();
    stateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            selectedState = stateSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            System.out.println("State "+selectedState+" has been selected");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    addItemsToTextView();
}
```

The Strings and the Spinners have already been declared and initialized above.